# 3 Column Bootstrap w/Sidebar in the middle

Tags: templates, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, sidebar

What I would like to achieve is a layout similar to what is being displayed in the following images: !(http://nerby.com.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/fb42.jpg)

If you notice the sidebar is to the left by default. Selecting the "About" link activates the right content area and sidebar to slide to the right.

I'm using the following template to have a starting point at recreating this layout concept but am stuck with this: http://mosaicpro.biz/adminplus/php/

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand correctly. If all you want is to have your sidebar on the left in the homepage, and on the right on the other pages, simply create two modules for the sidebar;

- the first must be assigned to the left sidebar position (find out the name in your template) and published only on selected pages (and choose the homepage in the list).
- The second must be assigned to the right sidebar position and published "except on these pages" (choosing the same pages as above)

this way Joomla will know which one to show.

If you however mean that it should smoothly "slide" to the right while the content is loaded, well that's a different ballpark and besides the animation you'll also need the ajax loading of content.